# High-dimensional clustering from aggregates of observations

Tags: data-mining, cluster-analysis, statistics

I have fallen into this weird high-dimensional clustering problem.  Here is an analogy to explain it.

Imagine that 2^10 people enter into a forest, and we want to know how many bird species live there.

These birds differ from each other in, say, 128 dimensions, and all dimensions are binary.  That is: either a bird has large beak or small beak, either it has a blue wing or it doesn't, etc.  (Each bird species can be represented by 128 bits)

My problem is that when the guys get off the forest, we only have *the aggregates* of their observations:

"I saw 8 birds, 3 had blue beaks (5 didn't), 4 had blue wings (4 didn't), 1 had a large beak (7 didn't), etc".  They *do not* report on the individual characteristics of their observations, but only on the aggregates of their observations.

There are two additional constraints:

i) all species are observed at least once;
ii) The number of species is small (~2^5).

Of course, we can compile the aggregate of their aggregates (of 3000 observations, 357 birds had large beaks, etc..).  But what about the clusters?

So the questions are:

1. How can we find out how many species live there?
2. How can we find out the characteristics of each species?

Answer (score 2):

Since `2^128 = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456`, you would need a pretty high sample size to draw valid conclusions. Every bird observed could easily be unique.

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add two constraints:

i) all species are observed at least once;
ii) The number of species is small (~2^5).

Thanks.  I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` an aggregate observation of a set of birds by a person, then you can approximate it by the matrix product `Dz` where `D` is a matrix whose columns represent characteristics of individual birds, and `z` is a vector of the counts of each bird.

If you assume that only a small number of birds are observed, then this acts as a constraint on the magnitude of `z`.

This problem is very similar to the sparse dictionary learning problem.

Here are a couple of links that both describe sparse dictionary learning (and related problems) and provide software to solve it: http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/ and http://www.ux.uis.no/~karlsk/dle/index.html